# Mostrar resultado con o sin decimales, cuando corresponda

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema y es que estoy haciendo una calculadora y al momento de imprimir números intenté usar `parseFloat` para poder operarlos, pero cuando no son números decimales y trabajo enteros, obtengo estos resultados.

¿Cómo podría hacer para que pueda obtener resultados decimales y además de que cuando trabaje con enteros el resultado sea entero?

```
output: 25 + 8 = 33.00

expected: 25 + 8 = 33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo utilizo el `+` para obligar a la variable a cambiar de tipo de dato. Ejémplos:

```js
let a = 25;
let b = +"8";
console.log(a + b);

a = +"25.20";
b = +"8.30";
console.log(a + b);

a = +"25";
b = +"8.00";

console.log(a + b);
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias :D